# Java list v/s Database list which one is expensive?

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I need to create a list of aproximately 50K records which needs to be inserted into database.

i can think of two approach which is better approach in terms of performance

1. Stored proc which accepts list of these objects and inserts them
2. construct list in java and for each record invoke database inserts using mybatis

Comment: Either way is good as per my knowledge, I would go with option 2 with mybatis batch.

Comment: You should really set up a test case for each approach and see what the performance is like with your data, hardware, network, etc

Comment: Batch inserts are directly supported by jdbc using standard SQL. Although batch implementation is not guaranteed to be supported by all databases, it is supported by the oracle jdbc driver, while oracle PLSQL is *only* supported by Oracle. Additionally with stored procedures you will have the additional complexity handling the passing of arrays.

Answer (score 4):

I think using `PreparedStatement` and batch inserts is your best bet. 
The benefit of PreparedStatement is that the sql is cached on the RDBMS server and bulk insert can be done in the form of batches.

Something like:

```
private void doInsert(Connection conn, List<Data> data){
    String sql = "INSERT INTO T (A,B,C) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement ps =  conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    int count = 0;
    for(Data d : data) {
        count++;
        ps.setString(1, data.getA());
        ps.setString(2, data.getB());
        ps.setString(3, data.getC());
        ps.addBatch();
        if (count%1000 == 0) {
            ps.executeBatch();
        }
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
    ps.close();
}
```

Comment: This is truly the best answer, because it addresses directly the java `List`, how to break it up in manageable batches (not always one single mega batch is the best), and how batches are handled in a standard jdbc way.

Answer (score 0):

The best performance will come from batches of insert statements, like the following:

```
insert into my_table (c1, c2, c3) values
    (v1, v2, v3),
    (v4, v5, v6),
    ...
```

If you split it into 50,000 insert statements, you will get much poorer performance. The less insert statements, the better. Each insert statement requires mysql to parse the query, and obtain and release locks on the necessary tables, not to mention starting and committing transactions. If you could do this all in 100 blocks of 500 rows, for example, you will cut out 49,900x this overhead.

You can improve performance even further if you want to use a LOAD DATA INFILE command, but that complicates matters a bit and may not be worth it depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: This isn't valid oracle syntax, though you can achieve similar results in various ways such as `insert into my_table(c1,c2,c3) select v1,v2,v3 from dual union all select v4,v5,v6 from dual union all ...` or `insert all into my_table(c1,c2,c3) values (v1,v2,v3) into my_table(c1,c2,c3) values (v4,v5,v6) ... select * from dual` all decidedly more verbose but they do achieve the desired result of keeping it all in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your best performance will be some form of bulk insert whether that's

**a multi record insert:**

```
insert into your_table(c1,c2,c3)
select v1, v2, v3 from dual union all
select v4, v5, v6 from dual union all
...
select vN, vO, vP from dual;
```

or

```
insert all
into your_table(c1,c2,c3) values (v1,v2,v3)
into your_table(c1,c2,c3) values (v4,v5,v6)
...
into your_table(c1,c2,c3) values (vN,vO,vP)
select * from dual;
```

**a bulk insert using native PL/SQL collections:**

```
FORALL i IN your_collection.first .. your_collection.last
  INSERT INTO your_table(c1,c2,c3)
  VALUES( your_collection(i).v1
        , your_collection(i).v2
        , your_collection(i).v3);
```

or

```
FORALL i IN INDICES OF your_collection
  INSERT INTO your_table(c1,c2,c3)
  VALUES( your_collection(i).v1
        , your_collection(i).v2
        , your_collection(i).v3);
```

**or a bulk insert using bind arrays:**

```
BEGIN
  FORALL i IN :lower .. :upper
    INSERT INTO your_table(c1,c2,c3)
    VALUES( :v1(i), :v2(i), :v3(i) );
END;
```

Comment: I doubt that proposed "multi record insert" will provide sufficient performance. The command would have a size of maybe 1 MByte (or 1 Million characters). Just sending and parsing such command will take some time. Most likely you have additional effort to send such command as CLOB.